# Any method to do auto-multiclass?

Tags: python, random

The purpose to gather random label is to see the difference between 2-3 clusters, and I am going to do machine learning(random forest) later.

So the question is, I want to concat label0 and label1 to one group, label2 and label3 to another group.

[image]

Then, random change the order of the label, like label0 with label2, label1 with label3,...and so on.
I don't know how to do it automatically.

The expected result is like this

[image]
[image: The expected result is like this]

Any solution? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got a solution to your problem:

```
import pandas as pd
import random

data = {
    'col1': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    'col2': [7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0],
    'label': ['0', '0', '1', '1', '2', '2', '3', '3']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
labels = list(df['label'].unique())

num_iterations = 10
for i in range(10):
    random.shuffle(labels)
    dfs = []
    for j in range(1, len(labels), 2):
        series = df[(df['label'] == labels[j-1]) | (df['label'] == labels[j])][['col1', 'col2']].agg('sum')
        new_label = labels[j-1] + ' ' + labels[j]
        new_df = series.to_frame().T.assign(label=new_label)
        dfs.append(new_df)
    shuffeled_df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

So I first take a list of the labels and shuffel it. Then selecting pairwise the labels and calculating the sum. This is done for all label pairs (in this iteration).
At the end a new combined DataFrame will be created.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your help, I guess it's almost there.
First of all, I want the value which is not sum, to be valued separately. (I edited below to make the expected answer more clearly, and I changed the examples to which you gave.)

Second, I guess if not to be sum, the process is easier probably.( Good to hear!)

Comment: Maybe just rewrite the `series=` row (not sure)

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the code, and I just revise your code a little bit.!
First, I delete `.agg('sum')`.
Then, I take off `to_frame().T`.
And it's done! 

Thanks a lot!!!